# Mathematica 10, With and ParallelEvaluate: New syntax?

Tags: parallelization, version-10

Consider the following trivial code to evaluate something on a parallel kernel

```
kernel = LaunchKernels[1];
res = With[{input = 3}, ParallelEvaluate[2 + input, kernel]]
CloseKernels[kernel];
```

On Linux, both version 8.0.4 and 9.0.1 return

```
5
```

but with 10.0.0, 10.0.2 and 10.1.0 I get

```
{5}
```

If this is not a bug, then I'm wondering why such a serious change of the syntax was not publicly announced in the release notes. Or may be I missed it somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recasting my comment as an answer, as suggested by [Leonid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin).

> `ParallelEvaluate` hasn't changed, the reason is that `LaunchKernels[1]` used to return a kernel object, while now it returns a single element list. I think this is more consistent, and the old behavior was never explicitly documented.